# Emulating NTFS USB drive using Zero W

Tags: usb, ntfs

I'd like to hook up my Zero W to my TV's USB jack.
The idea would be to transfer photos/videos from my laptop to my Pi via SSH, and they would appear on my TV.

There is an article that explains the process here:
https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/pi-zero-w-smart-usb-flash-drive

Question:
Instead of FAT32(as described in the article), how can I format to NTFS? This would allow me to add videos larger than 2GB.

EDIT:
LG WebOS only supports FAT32 and NTFS (no exFat)

Comment: The usual advice is not to use NTFS.  Use exFAT.

Comment: can the TV read NTFS formatted partitions?

Comment: WebOS only supports FAT32 and NTFS sadly

Comment: What is WebOS? On Linux the best choice is to use **ext4**.

Comment: WebOS is the TV OS from LG. I haven't tried ext4... Will try